# I can't open a new file to write to in perl

Tags: perl, output

I have looked on several links and other questions to try and find a solution but I still can't open the file that I'm trying to open. This is the block of code that I can't get to function:

```
$filename = "Related Traits: Chromosome 1";
open ($output1, ">", "gwasfiles4/$filename".".txt");
$length1 = scalar(@chr1);
if ($length1 > 1) {
    @chr1 = sort {$a <=> $b} @chr1;
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $length1; $x++){
        for ($y = $x + 1; $y <= $length1 - 1; $y++){
            if (abs($chr1[$x] - $chr1[$y]) < 500000){
                print $output1 "$chr1[$x]\t$chr1[$y]\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When  I run this, I got the error:

```
print() on closed filehandle $output at file.pl line 94
```

Why is the file not opened?

The file now opens with this but is empty:

```
my @chr1;
my $filename = "Related_Traits_Chromosome_1_$ARGV[0]";
open (my $output1, '>', "gwasfiles4/$filename") or die $!;
my $length1 = scalar(@chr1);
if ($length1 > 1) {
    @chr1 = sort {$a <=> $b} @chr1;
    for (my $x = 0; $x <= $length1; $x++){
        for (my $y = $x + 1; $y <= $length1 - 1; $y++){
            if (abs($chr1[$x] - $chr1[$y]) < 500000){
                print $output1 "$chr1[$x]\t$chr1[$y]\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `use autodie; use diagnostics;`

Comment: where would I put that?

Comment: `open my $output1, ">", "gwasfiles4/$filename.txt" or die $!;`. Also, put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your script, and fix any errors/warnings they produce.

Comment: Trying something on your own takes less time than asking.

Comment: That is returning "No such file or directory at line (line of that code)"

Comment: What do you get when you run `ls gwasfiles4` from within the directory the script is located in?

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't generate that warning. Please show the code around line 94, which should contain `print $output` (the filehandle mentioned in the warning), not `print $output1` (completely different filehandle).

Comment: `my $length1 = scalar(@chr1);` will never evaluate to true, as there's nothing in that array. For that reason, nothing is printed to your file. What's the purpose of that line? What is supposed to be in `@chr1`?

Answer (score 3):

`use strict;` and `use warnings;` should always be at the start of your program. Fix the errors they generate first, and you'll have better code.

So too - you should check the error code from `open`:

```
open my $output1, '>', "gwasfiles4/$filename.txt" or die $!;
```

This will print the error that `open` generated if it failed. I'll guess either `gwasfiles4` doesn't exist, or your OS doesn't like the filename with an embedded `:`.

If `strict` and `warnings` don't help enough, `use diagnostics;` will give you yet another layer of information about the problem.

`autodie` is particularly useful - it puts that `or die $!` line after each `open` statement automatically. (and a few other things besides).

I would suggest as a point of style - enclose your lexical filehandle in `{}` when printing, as this makes it very clear it's a filehandle.

```
print {$output1} "$chr1[$x]\t$chr1[$y]\n";
```

Edit:

Following your changes, you have a completely different problem:

```
my @chr1;                    #create empty array
my $length1 = scalar(@chr1); # scalar here takes length, array is empty, therefore length is _always_ zero. 
if ($length1 > 1) {          #therefore never happens
```

Comment: With single-quotes, the `$filename` won't be interpolated. I made the same typo ;)

Comment: I have strict and warnings on earlier in the code, this block is at about line 100.  I tried this and it opened the file but the file was empty which it should not be. Here is the exact code I used:

Comment: `my $filename = "Related_Traits_Chromosome_1_$ARGV[0]";
    open (my $output1, '>', "gwasfiles4/$filename") or die $!;
    my $length1 = scalar(my @chr1);
    if ($length1 > 1) {
     @chr1 = sort {$a <=> $b} @chr1;
     for (my $x = 0; $x <= $length1; $x++){
      for (my $y = $x + 1; $y <= $length1 - 1; $y++){
       if (abs($chr1[$x] - $chr1[$y]) < 500000){
        print $output1 "$chr1[$x]\t$chr1[$y]\n";
       }
      }
     }
    }`

Comment: probably worth editing that into your question, rather than posting as a comment.

Comment: @Jack `scalar(my @foo)` will always be zero. Nothing inside your `if` statement will run.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that either the directory `gwasfiles4` doesn't exist or you'rte working on a Windows system which doesn't allow colons `:` in its filenames

Comment: `gwasfiles4` does exist, I'm on a mac using text wrangler and can you please check the question again, I edited it. Thanks

Comment: @Jack: As others have said, `$length1` will always be zero in that code so your `if` block will never be executed

Comment: But in that case - you couldn't get a `print to closed filehandle` either.

Comment: Why would `$length1` always be zero and how can I fix that?

Comment: @Jack Because you're declaring a new empty array with `my @chr1`, and the length of an empty array is zero. How to fix that is an entirely different question from the one you originally asked, so it would probably be best to ask a new question.

Comment: @Sobrique The `print` is probably happening later in code the OP hasn't shown. Notice that the error message mentions filehandle `$output`, while the `print` in their snippet uses `$output1`.